# HtmlDecode is not working for the following string c#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, htmldecode

```
string testString = "a aa aaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa href=j&#97v&#97script&#x3A;&#97lert 1  ClickMe";
```

I used the following code to decode it,

```
 string a = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(testString);
 Console.WriteLine(a);
```

The output is still the same.

I have tried other options like  `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlEntity.DeEntitize` and HtmlDecode from other packages.

What am I missing?

Comment: `&#97` needs a semi-colon at the end: `&#97;`.

Comment: With this sort of problem, it can be helpful to take what you *expect* the output to be and run it through the opposite function, to see what comes out.

Comment: @AminGolmahalle Your last edit changed it. The &#97 should be &#97; which would give the "a" you edited in.